# How to obtain vcruntime140_1d.dll while respecting license agreements

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, msvcrt, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

- I have a valid Visual Studio 2017 Professional license.
- I have a library dependency built with Visual Studio 2019. This makes it necessary to have `vcruntime140_1d.dll` in order to be able to run a Debug version of this dependency.

**What is the rightful way to obtain this DLL without breaching the license agreements?**

(I am not going to distribute this DLL to clients, I only need if for my development process, e.g. debugging)

*Context:*
In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74114995, it is suggested that Visual Studio Build Tools can be used to obtain the said DLL, but it seems that these tools also have particular license terms when it comes to non-Community licensees.

Comment: The license only dictates distribution rights.  You are not distributing it.  So just copy the file from c:\windows\system32 or c:\windows\syswow64 (32-bit version).  If you want to feel better about it (?) then copy from (on my machine) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.36.32532\debug_nonredist.  This directory exists for the express purpose of your intended usage scenario.  For VS2017 start at C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: @HansPassant but for this I have to install the Community edition, and I'm not sure how "legal" that is in corporate environment.

Comment: No, don't copy it from my machine.  Replace "Community" with "Professional" on your machine.

Comment: I'm not talking about copying it from your machine (!?) I'm simply pointing out that VS2017 Professional I have doesn't have this particular debug DLL. It's only available if you install any VS2019 or VS2022, but I'm not sure if doing it 'legal"? Do you see what I'm trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio licences are normally issued per-user for a specified period of time. If you have a current subscription to use Visual Studio 14 or 15 (2015 or 2017), the subscription will also allow you to download Visual Studio 16 or 17 (2019 or 2022).

You can try out the new version of Visual Studio, and its Debug binaries as long as you don't distribute them.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Visual-Studio-Licensing-Whitepaper-July2023.pdf

In the [Visual Studio by subscription level](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/4/15454442-CF17-47B9-A65D-DF84EF88511B/Visual_Studio_by_Subscription_Level.xlsx) spreadsheet, a "Visual Studio Professional" subscription (columns H - L, rows 1810-1820), shows all four of the Visual Studio levels mentioned.